# Ionic 2 AngularJs simple get request on loopback server

Tags: angularjs, curl, ionic-framework, ionic2, loopback

I'm trying to make a simple `GET` request from my Ionic 2 app to a server running `Loopback API`. Loopback uses a nice interface to show `GET` and `POST` commands and gives the curl command for it. Right now, for the data I want to access, the curl command is: `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://IPADDRESS:3000/api/tests'`, where the `IPADDRESS` is the server's IP address.

In my Ionic 2 app I am trying to just make the app send a simple alert when a button is clicked, where the alert text is the data gathered from the server. I currently have `alert(this.http.get("http://IPADDRESS:3000/api/tests"));`, but then the alert just shows `[object Object]`. I know there is data for it to get since the Loopback side works. Here is my whole type script file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

/**
 * Generated class for the SignupPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup-page',
  templateUrl: 'signup-page.html',
})
export class SignupPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPage');
  }

  existingUser() {
    alert(this.http.get("http://IPADDRESS:3000/api/tests"));
  }

  joinNow() {

  }

}
```

I am new to Ionic and AngularJS, so any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but maybe try:

```
this.http.get("http://IPADDRESS:3000/api/tests")
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
   });
```

note that you have to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` to use the `.map` operator

Comment: That seems to have helped, but now I am getting `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`, which makes me think it's either a problem with how I'm getting data, or something in loopback I don't understand.

Comment: what do you expect to get? you usually can watch the object properties on chrome consle. otherwise try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` to get more insight from servers response data

Comment: That data is stored in a MySql database and I have it filled with dummy data right now:
[ { name: 'Hooply Lop', age: 45, id: 1 },
  { name: 'Granny Smith', age: 99, id: 2 },
  { name: 'Ford Prefect', age: 67, id: 3 } ]
So I expect to get that back

Comment: as you said you get 3 times `[object Object]` so everthing looks right to me as your dummy data are 3 sets. did you try the JSON.stringify() method?

Comment: The `JSON.stringify(data)` part worked! Thanks a lot!